# Different business application tools like K2.net and their advantages?

Tags: .net, playframework-2.0, k2

Our team is thinking of using `K2.net` tools for business applications.

I have already gone through the website and its advantages.

However, I'd like more info about similar products and any specific advantages of `K2`.

Kindly help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For similar products, you can check the following :

- [Bizflow](http://www.handysoft.com)
- [Nintex](http://www.nintex.com)

Several years ago (around 2008), we were using Bizflow as our main workflow engine. For some reason, our management decided to make a switch. The alternatives are K2 and Nintex. We ends up using K2 blackpearl, and here are some of the advantages compared to other products :

1. Compared to Bizflow, K2 offers better integration with Microsoft products. Two of the killer feature for us are : integrated windows authentication, and integration with Visual Studio.
2. K2 doesn't require us to use Sharepoint. AFAIK, Nintex does. And, since we don't use Sharepoint for our BPM apps, Nintex is definitely not the product for us.

PS : I'm not affiliated with K2 or any other product